# Retrieving the most recent posts from the users someone is following

Tags: sql, design-patterns, mysql, android, comparative-review

I have two different implementations for retrieving posts from the users someone is following and I want to know which one you would recommend using. First I'll show you the tables, and then the two implementations.

Post table

> id (PK)| poster_id (FK) | value | created_on

Repost table - necessary for both implementations

> reposter_id (FK) | post_id (FK) | created_on

Following table

> follower_id (FK) | followee_id (FK)

user_feed table - necessary only for second implementation

> user_id (FK) | post_id (FK) | created_on

First implementation:

Requires the repost table, but no `user_feed` table. Whenever a user posts something I don't have to add a row for each of their followers in the `user_feed` table, but the query seems much more computationally expensive.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.poster_id, p.value, p.created_at
    FROM post AS p
    WHERE p.'user_id'=23 OR (p.'user_id' IN SELECT 'followee' FROM following WHERE 'follower'=23)
    UNION
    SELECT p.id, p.poster_id, p.value, rp.reposter_id, rp.created_at
    FROM post AS p
    INNER JOIN repost AS rp
    ON rp.post_id = p.id
    WHERE p.'user_id'=23 OR (p.'user_id' IN SELECT 'followee' FROM following WHERE 'follower'=23)))
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 80;
```

Second implementation:

Requires the `user_feed` table and the repost table. I add a record to the `user_feed` table every time someone posts/reposts something. The record is added for each one of the poster's followers. I only keep, say, 120 records for any particular user in the `user_feed` table. If a post is made and a user already has 120 records in the user_feed table, the oldest record for that user is deleted and the new one takes its place. If a user requests more records than there are present in the `user_feed` table for them, then the first implementation is used to retrieve them.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.poster, p.value, p.created_at
    FROM post As p
    WHERE p.'id' IN (SELECT 'post_id' FROM user_feed WHERE 'user_id'=23)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 80;
```

Comment: May you provide the table creation scripts?

Comment: [check out my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671676/questions-on-scalability-of-getting-most-recent-posts-from-users-someone-is-foll/36672782?noredirect=1#comment60982696_36672782) it has the table creation scripts and updated query implementations